# Java Type Use annotation - How to read them

Tags: java, annotations

I'm using custom type use annotation. I can't read them from an object like any other regular annotation:

```
public class TestingAnnotations {



public static void main(final String[] args) {
     final @CustomAnnotation TypeAnnotated b = new @CustomAnnotation TypeAnnotated();
     System.out.println(b.getClass().getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class)); //<-- prints null :(
   }
}

@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface CustomAnnotation {

}

class TypeAnnotated {

}
```

So, how can I check b instance is annotated?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you can't with a local variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237813

Comment: hmmm... looks like is only for compiler warnings :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are actually not annotating the class....  a class is annotated when it looks like:

```
@CustomAnnotation
class TypeAnnotated {

}
```

after that you will get the annotation doing:

```
TypeAnnotated b = new TypeAnnotated();
System.out.println(b.getClass().getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class));
```

Comment: Yes, my intention is not to annotate the class but the object/instance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you actually want a local variabel annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE})
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}
```

Then this compiles just fine:

[image]