# Kotlin type annotation

Tags: kotlin, annotations

Consider the following annotation class

```kotlin
@Target(AnnotationTarget.TYPE)
annotation class ML(val size: Int)
```

By default, the retention policy is `RUNTIME`, thus this annotation must be accessible through reflection.

Now I have

```kotlin
val a: @ML(2) List<Int> = listOf(1)
```

which does compile, but, if examined in the debugger, one gets

```kotlin
a::class.annotations.size = 0
```

What am I doing incorrectly and what is the correct way to annotate types without wrapping things into classes and annotating properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you used:

```kotlin
b::class.annotations
```

Can be used to obtain the annotations on the class returned by `b`. `List` is not annotated with anything, so you get no annotations. Given the location where you put the annotation, you actually want to get the annotations for the return type of property `b`:

```kotlin
::b.returnType.annotations
```

**EDIT:** I thought `b` was a property. What you want to do is impossible, because annotation information isn't stored for local variables on the JVM. See this question: [Can I get information about the local variables using Java reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237813/elementtype-local-variable-annotation-type) (about Java but it's all the same). If `b` had been a class property or a top-level property, then what I showed would have applied.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: One thing that might change the solution: is `b` a local variable, a class property, or a top-level property?

Comment: It is a local variable.